# Does the idea of non-contact force violate the law of logic or mathematics?

Tags: forces, causality, interactions

I saw that some forces like gravity and electromagnetism, are called 'non-contact force'.

For example, in case of repel and attract magnetic forces, what does 'non-contact force' mean?

If the meaning of non-contact force is what I imagine and a non-contact force exists, I think by logic it should violate logic or mathematics.

Does the idea of non-contact force violate the law of logic or mathematics?

Comment: No, it only violates intuition. But nature does not cater to our intuition.

Comment: Gravity is not a force. Trying to make it one with labels like "non-contact force" only muddies the waters but it doesn't solve the scientific problem. Electromagnetism is a local field theory. It retains the concept of the "contact force" in form of "locality".

Answer (score 3):

The term "non-contact force" is simply shorthand for saying that some forces can act between objects that are not physically in contact with one another at a macroscopic level. Examples of non-contact forces are electrostatic forces, magnetic forces and gravity.

At an atomic level, however, all forces are non-contact forces. Even when one object apparently pushes or pulls another object, the atoms or molecules of the two objects do not actually touch one another. The electron shells of the atoms or molecules at the surfaces of the two objects repel one another as a result of the Pauli exclusion principle - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_force#Physical_origin. So the distinction between "contact" and "non-contact" forces does not exist at an atomic level.

An even more fundamental description of forces would be that they are due to the exchange of elementary particles called [gauge bosons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_boson). This applies to all forces apart from gravity, for which we do not yet have a quantum mechanical description.

I am not sure which laws of logic or mathematics you think might be violated here. If non-contact forces did violate such a law then this would just show that that particular area of logic or mathematics was not useful as a model of certain aspects of the real world.

Comment: "*At an atomic level, however, all forces are non-contact forces.*" Possibly that is because of the ambiguity in defining "contact" at a scale where not even shape let alone volume span can be distinctly defined.

Comment: @Steeven I agree.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly Newton found the idea of non-contact forces unacceptable:

> *“It is inconceivable that inanimate Matter should, without the Mediation of something else, which is not material, operate upon, and affect other matter without
> mutual Contact … That Gravity should be innate, inherent and essential to
> Matter, so that one body may act upon another at a distance thro’ a Vacuum,
> without the Mediation of any thing else, by and through which their Action and
> Force may be conveyed from one to another, is to me so great an Absurdity that
> I believe no Man who has in philosophical Matters a competent Faculty of
> thinking can ever fall into it.”* — Isaac Newton, 1692/3, *Letters to Bentley*

However, we may regard this problem as resolved in the standard model of particle physics, in which forces are transmitted by intermediate bosons, and also in general relativity, in which gravity is understood as being an inertial (or "fictitious") force, and is an effect of geometry.

One cannot view Newton's objection as being simply one of logic or mathematics, which concern only deduction from axioms. It is however necessary to our most fundamental laws of known physics that effects cannot be instantaneously transmitted (relativity) and that they cannot be transmitted without an intermediary (the continuity equation). Newton's remark is as true today as it ever has been.

Comment: The problem with Newton's statement is not remote mediation. The problem is that he demands remote mediation to be only possible through a material medium. We know that such a medium (usually called "ether") is not compatible with the observed laws of nature.

Answer (score 0):

We can define objects by measuring them with calipers.   That
means that the slight forces of contact become the definition
of the object's surface, so force and surface contact are closely related
in that scenario.

The forces of magnetism, and electric attraction and repulsion, however,
are not abruptly present at an object's surface, so  we  deal  with them
in a more general mathematical fashion, and oddities like optical refraction
in a birefringent crystal, or a graded-index  lens, require elaborate field
and wave treatments that are in no way similar to surfaces-in-contact.

There are no logical difficulties in dealing with a light beam as
photons with no mass but having momentum... but it's a very different
thing than an object with caliper-friendly dimensions, and requires
a more sophisticated application of mathematics.   So, the pushrod
and massive block may interact by contact, but the magnet and nail
have invisible and  intangible connection.   Not illogical, nor non
mathematical, just... obviously different in the human-scale visual
picture.

Answer (score 0):

I think all forces are physical and the use of the phrase "non contact" is confusing... remote contact is a little better... because it implies contact at a distance... forces generated at a distance from specific objects that are capable of doing so...

Comment: The problem is that it is not "the remote object" that creates the local force but the local field. This is evidently obvious in the retarded potential form of the solutions of Maxwell's equations. Even if the remote source starts moving the motion does not immediately translate to a change of force on a local observer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/396661)